# What's the algorithm for finding sequences used by TraMineR?

Tags: r, algorithms, traminer, sequential-pattern-mining

I'm working an analysis about finding frequent sequences in a event-state dataset using the R package `TraMineR` (and `arulesSequences` too).
In `arulesSequences` the algorithm used to find frequent sequences is the cSPADE algorithm.

But what is the algorithm `TraMineR` uses for the function `seqefsub`?
Does it use the GSP algorithm or the cSPADE algorithm as well? I couldn't find any information about that in the user guide and other information material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in Ritschard et al. (2013), the algorithm implemented in TraMineR is an adaptation of the prefix-tree-based search described in Masseglia (2002).

- Masseglia, F. (2002). Algorithmes et applications pour l'extraction
  de motifs sequentiels dans le domaine de la fouille de donnees : de
  l'incremental au temps reel. Ph. D. thesis, Universite de
  Versailles Saint-Quentin en Yvelines.
- Ritschard, G., Bürgin, R. & Studer, M. (2013), "Exploratory Mining of
  Life Event Histories", In McArdle, J.J. & Ritschard, G. (eds) 
  Contemporary Issues in *Exploratory Data Mining in the Behavioral 
  Sciences*. Series: Quantitative Methodology, pp. 221-253. New York: 
  Routledge.